# пустые функции возвращают значение

Tags: php

Копался в коде laravel, просто глянуть что как, поучиться чему нибудь, и ума не приложу как так. Вот код:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Database;

interface ConnectionResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * Get a database connection instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface
     */
    public function connection($name = null);

    /**
     * Get the default connection name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultConnection();

    /**
     * Set the default connection name.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDefaultConnection($name);
}
```

То есть, к примеру, функция `getDefaultConnection()`... Она же ничего не делает. Как она может возвращать дефолтное название соединения по умолчанию.

Comment: *interface* ConnectionResolverInterface...

Comment: @Ипатьев понял)) пойду про интерфейсы почитаю)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.interfaces.php